# RestClientException : in spring controller

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to catch an error scenario in my controller but I'm getting an exception in all cases.

Below is my code snippet:

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(RestClientException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Not Found")
public void restClientException()
{
  //do nothing
}

public List<myfile> getAllmyfiles() throws RestClientException
{
  return myfileService.getAllmyfiles();
}
```

Comment: What am i doing wrong in my code? am pretty new to spring. Am trying to catch exception if server is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some confusion here.
When the server is unreachable, your controller will not be available, it will not work.

If you want to do some logic when the server is unavailable, you have to do it in your front-end (for instance, JS). You can't do it in your Controller object.